# SQLite used in production mode even if postgres is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app works fine in development mode. I then switch to production mode by doing `bundle install --without development test`. When I try to run rake (`rake routes`) I get this error:
"

> rake aborted! Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database
>   adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your
>   Gemfile

My Gemfile has:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.10'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

My `config/database.yml` looks like:

```
default: &default
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: prod
  username: produser
```

My Gemfile.lock after `bundle install --without production test` has

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
     ...
    pg (0.18.3)
    ...
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
    ...
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    ...

DEPENDENCIES
  ...
  pg (= 0.18.3)
  ...
  rails_12factor (0.0.3)
  ...
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.10)
  ...

BUNDLED WITH
  1.10.6
```

I have updated to the Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.2.4, done `gem update system` and `bundle update` all to no avail.

Another question I have is why should the `sqlite3` gem show up in my `Gemfile.lock` in production mode? Similarly, why does the `pg` gem show up in development mode?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake routes` uses the default environment - which is development.

You need to either:

```
rake routes RAILS_ENV=production
```

or set the RAILS_ENV environment variable to 'production'